# Node.js server side checks

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following route `router.post('/reportDetails', reportSubmit);` where on submitting the form on the page i do the following check in the callback reportSubmit.js

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next){
    if(req.body && req.body.reportOptions !== 0 && req.body.reportSummary !== "" && req.body.reportWebAddress !== "" && req.body.reportDescription !== ""){
        res.redirect('viewreports');
    }
};
```

What should be the return value in the **else** condition for the above?

Comment: What do you want it to do if that condition fails? ;)  if it's an error case you could res.sendStatus(<some http error code>)...

Comment: i want the user to know that there was server side error and stay on the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the "stay on the same page" implementation is gonna depend on how you implemented the UI (server rendered templates and just form submission vs ajax or an SPA).

But what you'd probably want to do is just make it return a 400 bad request via

```
res.sendStatus(400)
```

or

```
res.status(400) // difference here is you can chain on other response methods such as res.json http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.json
```

Comment: Currently its server rendered templates with form submissions, if i were to do res.status(400).json({error:'Please check again'}); I should be able to render that error object on to the page

Comment: alternately you can do res.status(400).render("sometemplate", {error: "some error"}) where your template reads error and puts it into an error box or something